# Incorrect preferredStatusBarStyle when controller animated transitioning is canceled

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition, ios-statusbar

I have a `UITabViewController` which embeds some `UIViewControllers`. These controllers could have a different `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

I use a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning+UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` to switch between controllers using a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`.

I noticed that if i start a transitioning between two controllers with different `preferredStatusBarStyle` and i cancel the transitioning, the status bar style does not return to the first controller preference but it remains to the second one. Obviously if i complete the transitioning, or switch between controllers using the tab bar items, the status bar style changes correctly.

I tried to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in every `viewWillAppear`, but the status bar does not change.

I know i can change the status bar style with `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle` setter, but this method is now  deprecated.

I also tried to change the animation for the transitions, but the problem does not disappear.

The strange thing is that the `preferredStatusBarStyle` of the "from" view controller, when the transition is canceled, is set to the correct value, but it is displayed as the opposite!

Comment: can you try to call it in viewDidAppear ?

Comment: Are you calling `transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)` even when animation is cancelled ?

Comment: @BrahamYoussef yes and it does not change the status bar style.

Comment: @CZ54 Yes in the completion block of the UIView.animateKeyframes

Comment: can you send me the code ?

Comment: @BrahamYoussef you can use the tab bar demo of this library [link](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/VCTransitionsLibrary) and set the status bar style to .lightContent in one controller and to .default to another, and try to switch between these two controllers and cancel the transition (stop the gesture before the animation will complete the transition)

Comment: Can you try calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` with a `UIView` animation method in your `viewWillAppear`? The animation might help with the race condition by introducing a delay. Just a thought. Try it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem (it's not perfect but it works out)

In the `viewWillAppear` of the first controller (the "from" one), call this animation.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

In this way, when you cancel the transition, for a moment you'll see the status bar of the second view controller and then the status bar will return to the first controller one.

Comment: Oh, well. So you have already done this. I just added a comment in your question. Happy that this fixes the issue.

Comment: @nayem Sorry, I saw your comment after posting my answer. Thanks anyway